# How do I use the giant pink pyramids?

Tags: rad

Occasionally while underground I have come across a large glowing pink pyramid, similar to the smaller ones that seem to serve as lights, but off the path in a similar fashion to the shops and the machines that give endo mutations. Every time I try to interact with these pink pyramids, the narrator tells me something along the line of "Not ready yet" or "Can't do anything here." What do I need to do for these pyramids to be interactable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pyramids are free level-ups for your exo mutations. They cannot be used if you hit the exo mutation level cap for all your exo mutations.